# JSF Performance Session Scope vs Requested Scoped - Permission

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I would like to improve the performance of my JSF Web application.
Currently I stored a lot of permisson fields in the database as String.
I´m using a lot ot "rendered" in the JSF page to check if the user is allowed to see the link / datatable.
For each "rendered" I have a request to my JSF bean (this is RequestedScoped).
My question is:
Is it better to use instead of RequestedScoped a SessionScoped which holds the Permission object?

Currently:

```
<p:menuitem value="Test"
                        rendered="#{permissionCheckController.checkPermission(null, 'CREATE_COMMENT')}" />
```

checkPermission() includes round about 80 if conditions to check if the user is allowed to see/use the functionality and return true or false. In this example for "CREATE_COMMENT".

Is it better to use for example (and set the Bean to SessionScoped):

```
<p:menuitem value="Test"
                        rendered="#{permissionCheckController.myPermissionobject.createComment}" />
```

Thank you fr any feedback

Comment: Measuring is knowing.

Comment: You've got many options here. One would be to use the session scope, but, as the bottleneck is related to your DB reading operations, you could also consider using some kind of cache at service level.

Comment: Ok thank you. Which kind of options are also possible?

Comment: Second level cache as mentioned by @XtremeBiker